# Translate the words "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", & "Seconds" to locale equivalent

Tags: javascript, time, locale

I don't want to convert numeric times to different locales, but this is what all my searches lead me to.  I need to convert the actual words "Days", "Hours", etc. to the user's locale equivalent (e.g. "Jours", "Heures", etc.), and I need the abbreviations also.

Is this doable natively in JavaScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat):

> The Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor for objects that enable
> language-sensitive date and time formatting.

An example:

```js
var date = new Date();
let o = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-FR" , {
    timeStyle: "full",
    dateStyle: "full"
});
console.log(o.format(date));
```

Comment: Where are the words "jours heures minutes secondes"?  I only see "heure".

Comment: in the doc the possible values for minutes and sec are: "numeric", "2-digit"

Comment: I see.  So it's just a coincidence that the `"fr-FR"` locale includes the word "heure".  The only guaranteed translations are the month and day of the week.  There is no general way to translate the words "day", "hour", "minute", or "second".

Comment: I'm sorry. If you execute the snippet you can see the words **heure, septembre**.  For the moment, javascript can offer only the translation for some components of a date. Yes, this is a limit. But consider you can translate a lot, like dayweek, hours, months...... If you need more it is necessary a special lib, like momentjs.

Comment: Am I correct that the answer is: It is not possible right now. The accepted answer doesn't solve the issue, which was to translate the word "days" etc.

Comment: Partially, js doesn't cover all possible translations

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a translation with the [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat) api.

```js
// The date to translate (it can be also milliseconds)
const now = new Date();
// The language (ie locale). We choose French 
const locale = "fr";
// For the browser language
// const locale = window.navigator.language;;

// Choose the parts that you want to show
// We have chosen hour, minute, and second. Add second, day, month, year if you want them to be parsed
const format = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
   hour: "numeric",
   minute: "numeric",
   hour12: false
});
// Parse the date into parts
const dateParts = Object.fromEntries(format.formatToParts(now).map(e => [e.type, e.value]));
// The relative time formatter that will translate the time unit (ie minute, hour, ...)
const relativeFormatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, {});
// The string value for the hour part
const hour = dateParts["hour"];
// The hour parts translated
const  hourTranslatedParts = relativeFormatter.formatToParts(Number(hour),"hour");
// The string value for the minute part
const minute = dateParts["minute"];
// The minute parts translated
const  minuteTranslatedParts = relativeFormatter.formatToParts(Number(minute),"minute");
// console
console.log(`The actual hour in French is: ${hourTranslatedParts[1].value}${ hourTranslatedParts[2].value}, ${minuteTranslatedParts[1].value}${ minuteTranslatedParts[2].value}`);
```